# Подключение php к бд ошибка. помогите

Tags: php, mysql

Подключаю php к бд у меня выходить ошибка:

```
    Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in E:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\views\teams.php on line 9
Не удалось выбрать базу:
```

вот код

```html
<?php
 //Подключение к базе данных

    $host = 'localhost'; // адрес сервера 
    $database = 'teams-bd'; // имя базы данных
    $user = 'root'; // имя пользователя
    $password = 'Timur__1'; // пароль
   // подключаемся к серверу
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) ;
    if (!$link) echo "Ошибка " . mysql_error($link);
    // выполняем операции с базой данных
    $db_selected *= mysql_select_db($database, $link);
    if (!$db_selected) 
    die ('Не удалось выбрать базу: ' . mysql_error());
   
  ?>
```

Comment: `mysql` устарела, воспользуйтесь `mysqli` или лучше `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

Расширение `mysql` устарело. И будет удалено в дальнейшем. 
Для решения Вашей задачи, воспользуйтесь либо `mysqli`, либо используйте `PDO`.
Пример запроса `PDO`:

```php
        //Раздел подключения к БД лучше вынести в отельный файл и подключать тут через `require`.
        // YourDB - название базы данных
        // YourHost - ip адрес базы данных
        // YourName - имя пользователя mysql
        // YourPass - пароль пользователя mysql
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=YourDB;host=YourHost', 'YourName', 'YourPass');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        // table - название Вашей таблицы
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bz` WHERE `USER` = '1' AND `VAR` = :var"; // Ваш запрос в БД

        $req = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        $req->bindValue(':var', $var, PDO::PARAM_STR); //Данные, которые передаёте в запрос
        $req->execute();
        $array = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Возвращаем значение.
```